# Porque en la pagina donde se listan los usuarios que hay en la base de datos no carga

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de crear un listado de usuarios registrados con la informacion que tengo en una base de datos pero la pagina donde debe aparecer el listado al utilizar el localhost me sale con esto como podría solucionarlo? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error creo debe estar en esta parte del codigo

```
@Controller

public class ListadoControlador {

    @Autowired
    private ListadoService listadoService;

    @GetMapping ("PaginaAdmin")
    public String listarUsuarios(@RequestParam(name = "page",defaultValue = "0")int page,Model modelo){
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page,4);
        Page<Usuario> usuarios = listadoService.findAll(pageRequest);
        PageRender<Usuario> pageRender = new PageRender<>("/PaginaAdmin", usuarios);
        
        modelo.addAttribute("titulo","Listado de usuarios");
        modelo.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarios);
        modelo.addAttribute("page", pageRender);
        
        return "PaginaAdmin";
    }
    
}
```

o posiblemente en alguna es estas partes[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en otras ocasiones e podido hacer que habra la pagina pero la tabla me sale sin los datos correspondientes que tengo en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El largo mensaje de error, del cual compartes una porción como imagen, te dice **exactamente** dónde está el error. Entonces, revisa ese mensaje, cerca de donde dice *`Caused by`* ahí está el error. Si no sabes revisarlo, entonces pon la traza completa del error como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Intente buscar el Cuased by por medio de Ctrl + F pero no esta creo el error esta en el mapping pero no tengo la menor idea del por que

Comment: Pon puntos de interrupción para verificar si el problema está ahí realmente.

Comment: sigue sin marcarme cual es el error voy a subir imágenes del resto del código a ver si se encuentra el problema

Comment: El error dice que algo es nulo... que es nulo? es imposible saberlo, puede ser un parametro, lo que devuelve la DB.. puede ser cualquier cosa, la unica forma de detectarlo, es seguir paso a paso el codigo y ver que esta siendo nulo (si es que la traza del error no lo dice ya)...

Comment: ¿No sabes depurar el código? Es hora de aprender, te ahorrarás muuuuchas horas y muuuuchos días y muuuuchos dolores de cabeza y desánimos. Como dije, pon puntos de interrupción, y encontrarás rápido el problema. Nosotros no podemos depurar el código por ti y con imágenes menos.

Comment: no tienes un tutorial para como hacerlo marco los puntos de interrupcion pero spring boot igual sigue sin detenerse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final sabrá dios que estaba mal simplemente cambie por otro método para listar usuarios y santo remedio

para el registrocontrolador.java

```
@GetMapping("/PaginaAdmin/new")
public String listStudents(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("usuario", usuarioServicioImpl.getAllUsuarios());
    return "PaginaAdmin";
}
```

para usuariorepositorio.java

```
 @Query(value = "FROM Usuario s WHERE s.Primernombre LIKE :name OR s.Segundonombre LIKE :name")
    public List<Usuario> findByNameContaining(@Param("name") String name);
```

En usuarioservicios.java

```
List<Usuario> getAllUsuarios();
Usuario getUsuarioById(Long id);
```

En usuarioserviciosimpl.java

```
@Override
    public List<Usuario> getAllUsuarios() {
        return usuarioRepositorio.findAll();
    }


    @Override
    public Usuario getUsuarioById(Long id) {
        return usuarioRepositorio.findById(id).get();
    }
```

y la parte de Html

```
                    <tbody >
                        <tr  th:each="usuario : ${usuario}">
                            <td th:text="${usuario.id}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.usuarioS}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.Primernombre}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.Segundonombre}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.Primerapellido}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.Segundoapellido}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.FechaDeNacimiento}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${usuario.Edad}"></td>
              <td th:text="${usuario.email}"></td>
              <td th:text="${usuario.password}"></td>


                            <td ><a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                                th:href="${usuario.id}">Editar</a></td>
                            <td> 
                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                th:href="${usuario.id}"
                                onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar el usuario?');">Eliminar</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).